# undoing git commit after rebase

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am new to all this git commit stuff. I followed these commands:

```
git commit -m "my message"
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

then I got conflict. I have got the problem and now want to revert this commit.
How do I do that?

Comment: If you have a conflict, your rebase is not finished (and `git status` should say that you are in the middle of a conflicted rebase).  If you wish to abort the rebase effort, follow the advice that `git status` gives you.

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase --abort` will reset `HEAD` to where it was when the rebase operation was started.